# Using auto.arima: Error in OCSBtest(x, m) : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

I'm using a big (isplit) loop on a huge set of Time Series for testing on ARIMA models. For this I'm using the `auto.arima` function from the `forecast` package.

For this I created a function, to traverse all the time series while keeping track of progress and store fitted models and stats (such as accuracy and model parameters). Now I'm dealing with an error generated by the `auto.arima` function. To be more precise; caused by the OCSB seasonal testing.

I'm using this function for 'monthly' time series as well as for 'weekly' time series. For monthly time series a have no problems (almost 50000, including a lot with 'zero' values). With the weekly time series I ran into the problem. But I'm not able to find the real cause of the Error.

I tried to recreate the error. I though about it had something to do with a lot of 0 (or the same) values in combination with the 52 frequency period. But I still can't point the finger at the problem.

See the examples below. Some info: the set of time series are weekly values (freq=52), starting in 2010, week 1. The length is 122 samples (until 2012, week 18). Therefore I tested with lengths of 122, for which I can generate the error. I still think it has something to do with the frequency and 'running same values'...

For some the error is generated, for some not.

Example 1 [random numbers, length=122] > no problem:

```
ts_element <- ts(sample(0:30, 122, replace=TRUE), frequency = 52, start = c(2010, 1))
fit <- auto.arima(ts_element, trace=FALSE, seasonal.test="ocsb", allowdrift=TRUE, stepwise=TRUE)
```

Example 2 [only 0 values, length=122] > the OCSB test Error (normally I would assume a different error...see example 3):

```
ts_element <- ts(sample(0:0, 122, replace=TRUE), frequency = 52, start = c(2010, 1))
fit <- auto.arima(ts_element, trace=FALSE, seasonal.test="ocsb", allowdrift=TRUE, stepwise=TRUE)
Error in OCSBtest(x, m) : subscript out of bounds
```

Example 3 [only 0 values, length=100] > the 'zero/equal values' error, I assumed this one, this example is not the problem, but to point out that the length is relevant (compare with example 2):

```
ts_element <- ts(sample(0:0, 100, replace=TRUE), frequency = 52, start = c(2010, 1))
fit <- auto.arima(ts_element, trace=FALSE, seasonal.test="ocsb", allowdrift=TRUE, stepwise=TRUE)
Error in if (PVAL == min(tablep)) warning("p-value smaller than printed p-value") else warning("p-value greater     than printed p-value") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Example 4 [almost the same as ex.3, but with one non-0 value, length=100] > no problem anymore:

```
ts_element[30] <- 1
fit <- auto.arima(ts_element, trace=FALSE, seasonal.test="ocsb", allowdrift=TRUE, stepwise=TRUE)
```

Example 5 [almost the same as ex.4, but length=122] > the OCSB test Error:

```
ts_element <- ts(sample(0:0, 122, replace=TRUE), frequency = 52, start = c(2010, 1))
ts_element[30] <- 1
fit <- auto.arima(ts_element, trace=FALSE, seasonal.test="ocsb", allowdrift=TRUE, stepwise=TRUE)
Error in OCSBtest(x, m) : subscript out of bounds
```

Example 6 [random 1's and 0's, length=122] > no problem:

```
ts_element <- ts(sample(0:1, 122, replace=TRUE), frequency = 52, start = c(2010, 1))
fit <- auto.arima(ts_element, trace=FALSE, seasonal.test="ocsb", allowdrift=TRUE, stepwise=TRUE)
```

Example 7 [random numbers, smaller length of 50] > no problem:

```
ts_element <- ts(sample(1:34, 50, replace=TRUE), frequency = 52, start = c(2010, 1))
fit <- auto.arima(ts_element, trace=FALSE, seasonal.test="ocsb", allowdrift=TRUE, stepwise=TRUE)
```

Does anybody have an idea what the cause of this the OCSB out of bounds Error is?
How to recognize?

The main problem is that whenever this error occurs in the function I described in the beginning of this post, the function doesn't output all the information I'm gathering. So the hours of waiting is for nothing.
So if the root cause cannot be found, I'm also very much helped with some code to deal with Errors in a way to 'ignore' them (skip that time series) and go further. Or ignore, but still output the information gathered at that moment.

How has the solution?

Note: the zero-error is not a problem. I'm covering this in my function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nice question, and well explained. You clearly thought this through before you submitted.

The problems in your examples are due to a number of issues (and in my opinion, bugs) around dealing with time series full of zeroes.

In general, you should use the `debug` command to step through your code. For example, try debugging the five main functions that run for the `auto.arima`:

```
debug(auto.arima)
debug(nsdiffs)
debug(forecast:::OCSBtest)
debug(lm)
debug(lm.fit)
```

(use `Q` to exit and `undebug` to stop debugging a function) and then try running your code in **Example 2**

```
ts_element <- ts(sample(0:0, 122, replace=TRUE), frequency = 52, start = c(2010, 1))
fit <- auto.arima(ts_element, trace=FALSE, seasonal.test="ocsb", allowdrift=TRUE, stepwise=TRUE)
```

After a lot pressing `Enter` you will finally reach the point where R fails. In this case, it is a rather deep and nasty bug in `lm.fit`. If all the coefficients are zero, then for some reason it converts them to `NA`. When the `OCSBtest` function tries to pull out the coefficients, it find the matrix empty, and tells you that it is not an appropriate index.

I would tell you to report this to R-bugs... but they can be pretty snippy when it comes to bugs in `base`. They will probably tell you it is "user error" and that you shouldn't be fitting regression models to all zeroes (sigh).

The first problem with **Example 3** appears to be a feature undocumented in the `nsdiffs` page, which describes the  `forecast::OCSBtest` function. It looks like your time series must be bigger than 2 times the period + 5, or the seasonal differencing will not be run. In **Example 2** this was true, but not in **Example 3**. Indeed, the very first bit of the code in the function is:

```
if (length(time.series) < (2 * period + 5)) {
    return(0)
}
```

Read up in the two Osborn references listed in the `nsdiffs` page, maybe it mentions it there somewhere. It would be a good idea to let the authors of `forecast` know so they could include it in the documentation somewhere. Maybe even throw a warning, with an option to turn it off.

**Example 3** has a different error than **Example 2** is because **Example 3** immediately exits the `nsdiffs` function, and then goes on to fail in the `ndiff` function, which does the differencing. `ndiff` appears to have a bug in which if the sum of square differences is zero (because the series is zero), then it causes a divide by zero error. Here is the relevant code in the `ndiff` function:

```
s2 <- .C("R_pp_sum", as.vector(e, mode = "double"), as.integer(n), as.integer(l), s2 = as.double(s2), PACKAGE = "tseries")$s2
STAT <- eta/s2 # Becomes NaN
PVAL <- approx(table, tablep, STAT, rule = 2)$y # Also NaN
if (is.na(approx(table, tablep, STAT, rule = 1)$y)) if (PVAL == 
min(tablep)) warning("p-value smaller than printed p-value") else warning("p-value greater than printed p-value") # Bombs
```

**Example 4** succeeds because `s2` is never zero. A simple fix would be to check if `s2` was zero before dividing.

**Example 5** fails for much the same reason as **Example 2**. It enters the `nsdiff` function because it has a length of more than `2*period+5`, and then fails because `lm.fit` doesn't return the coefficients when they are all zero.

**Example 6** succeeds because `lm.fit` will now properly return the coefficients, because they are not all zero, because your time series is mixed with ones and zeroes.

**Example 7** succeeds because `nsdiff` is not run (because the series is too small) and `ndiff` will no longer cause a divide by zero, because the sum of squared differences will not be zero.

In conclusion, your examples have shown two bugs. One in `ndiff` when the time series is always zero, and another in the `lm.fit` function when the covariates are all zero. Also, the documentation in `nsdiff` should be updated to tell you that it won't be run if the time series has a length of less than `2*period+5` if you use the 'ocsb' option (but maybe this is documented in the references).

Comment: Note as well that there is a mistake in the references in the `nsdiffs` documentation. The title of the second Osborn reference should be: "A survey of seasonality in UK macroeconomic variables". I could not find any reference to `2*period+5`.

Comment: Wow! Great and extensive answer. You really took time to analyze this. Thanks for that. This helps me a lot. In general, the errors are cause by 'a lot of zero's', so that's information I can use. I'm now using `tryCatch` to handle the error's and storing information on those errors.

Comment: It would be really a good idea for you to report this to the authors of forecast. They'll fix it pretty soon and you won't have to write the code to catch the errors.